# How can I disable the 'My Site' landing page in Docusaurus

Tags: reactjs, docusaurus

I created a "How to Use" document in which I want to directly show the Tutorial page. How can I Disable the 'My Site' Landing page?

I try to change the parameters on docusaurus.config.js, with to avail.

Comment: Have you tried to delete `./src/pages/index.js`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do three things:

1. In the Markdown file that's your tutorial landing page (such as `intro.md` or `index.md` or whatever you're using), add this inside the front matter:
   `slug: /`
2. Delete `src/pages/index.js`, or rename the file to `_index.js`.
3. In `docusaurus.config.js`, find the `presets` array. Add `routeBasePath: '/'` as a property of the `docs` object in that array. Like this:

```
  presets: [
    [
      'classic',
      /** @type {import('@docusaurus/preset-classic').Options} */
      ({
        docs: {
          sidebarPath: './sidebars.js',
          routeBasePath: '/'
        },
  ...
```

That should do it.

This is called "docs-only mode". You can read more about it here: https://docusaurus.io/docs/docs-introduction#docs-only-mode